# how does javafx compares 2 colors and knows they are the same or different?

Tags: netbeans, javafx

I'm doing an project for school, we have to make the game memory, i think you all know the game. Our problem is that we don't understand how javafx compares two 'cards'

The code we have now is for 4 cards and you can click on them and they wil turn into a color and when you click they will turn back. Can you guys please help me?

My current code is like this:

```
rectangle:rectangle1 = Rectangle { 
    width: 50 
    height: 50 
    x: 10 
    y: 50 
    arcWidth: 10 
    arcHeight: 10 
    fill: bind Color.web(kleur1) 
    onMouseClicked: function(event) { 
        if (kleur1 == "red"){ 
            kleur1 = "blue"
        } 
        else if (kleur1 == "blue") { 
            kleur1 = "red"} 
        } 
}
```

Comment: Please post the source code relevant to the problem you're having.

Comment: rectangle:rectangle1 = Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 10
                y: 50
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kleur1)
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kleur1 == "red"){
                        kleur1 = "blue"}
                    else if (kleur1 == "blue") {
                        kleur1 = "red"}
                    }
                }

Comment: ik tried this:                                                       if (kleur1 = "blue" and kleur3 = "blue") { rectangle1 = visible false and rectangle3 = visible false }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you need to check if the Color is equal

```
 if(kleur1.equals("blue") && kleur3.equals("blue"))
 {
      rectangle1.setVisible(false);
      rectangle3.setVisible(false);
 }
```

and do set visible like above

Comment: thank you, but it gives ! signs now and i don't know what to do about it

Comment: i don't know what to do next, maybe you can give me your email adress and i can send you the whole code like it is now

Comment: you need to spend some time and formulate the question correctly above and add the code in the question so its easy to read. you need to indent the code for it to show up correctly

Comment: New question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494595/making-a-memory-game-how-to-let-cards-disappear-when-they-are-the-same